# attaching WNDPROC function from child class

Tags: c++, winapi

I have a problem with attaching a windows procedure to a window.

I have a baseclass called `BaseWindow`, that uses `GWPL_USERDATA` to call a virtual function called `HandleMessage()` of the child classes.

However, if i try to change the window procedure without creating a custom Window Class, it gives a type error from the child procedure to long.

Here's the code:

```
static LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProc(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    BaseWindow *pThis = NULL;

    if (uMsg == WM_NCCREATE)
    {
        CREATESTRUCT* pCreate = (CREATESTRUCT*)lParam;
        pThis = (BaseWindow*)pCreate->lpCreateParams;
        SetWindowLongPtr(hwnd, GWLP_USERDATA, (LONG_PTR)pThis);

        pThis->m_hwnd = hwnd;
    }
    else
    {
        pThis = (BaseWindow*)GetWindowLongPtr(hwnd, GWLP_USERDATA);
    }
    if (pThis)
    {
        return pThis->HandleMessage(uMsg, wParam, lParam);
    }
    else
    {
        return DefWindowProc(hwnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
    }
}

virtual LRESULT HandleMessage(UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
    {return 0;};


PlayList Class : BaseWindow

SetWindowLong(m_hwnd, GWL_WNDPROC,(long)  HandleMessage); //Error

LRESULT PlayList::HandleMessage(UINT message,WPARAM wParam,LPARAM lParam) //Need to     attach this window procedure
{}
```

It works if the child procedure is static, however I use non static members in that procedure.

I want to subclass a common control, while using this base class (because a lot of code is redundant), is it possible?

Here's the whole code for the base class: http://pastebin.com/ME8ks7XK

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The compiler doesn't like your declaration for HandleMessage, it isn't static.  It's missing CALLBACK too, not good.

Not sure why you are trying to do this, the whole point of your WindowProc() function is to get the message forwarded to a virtual HandleMessage() method.  At best you'd use WindowProc in your SetWindowLong() call instead of HandleMesssage.  Or just specify it directly in the CreateWindowEx() call.

Comment: CALLBACK doesn't help .. and the handlemessage() works fine if i create a window class and register it(but this specific window is subclassing a system class[listbox]), why i don't want to use it in CreateWindowEx() is beacause i want it as a child of the base class, so i don't have to repeat the whole code ( eg pos,size,curr handle etc which is present in the base class)

Comment: That's not possible, the Windows api is C, it doesn't know how to call virtual C++ methods.  You are aware you are re-inventing a huge wheel?  C++ class libraries that wrap the api are plentiful.

Comment: or i'd have to make an exception to this one window(or any other that subclasses a system class), could there be any other solution?

Comment: marked as correct because i program in c++, win32 api is c, i  keep forgetting that:)

Answer (score 0):

From MSDN:

> An application subclasses an instance of a window by using the SetWindowLong function. The application passes the GWL_WNDPROC flag, the handle to the window to subclass, and the **address** of the subclass procedure to SetWindowLong. The subclass procedure can reside in either the application's executable or a DLL.

So, you should write this:
`SetWindowLong(m_hwnd, GWL_WNDPROC,(long) & HandleMessage);`

But this doesn't compile again! the reason: all non-static member functions have hidden `this` parameter (pointer to owner class). So, you `HandleMessage` doesn't fit the `WindowProc` declaration.